# What does [safe] marker mean in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

```
Prelude Data.Void> :info Void
data Void       -- Defined in `Data.Void'
instance [safe] Eq Void -- Defined in `Data.Void'
instance [safe] Ord Void -- Defined in `Data.Void'
instance [safe] Read Void -- Defined in `Data.Void'
instance [safe] Show Void -- Defined in `Data.Void'
```

What does [safe] mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply means that the datatype is defined in a module which is defined using safe extension. You can find the details of the extension [in the user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html).

In fact, you can test that yourself by defining a module using the `Safe` extension:

```
{-#LANGUAGE Safe#-}

data Test = Test deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And then trying it out in `ghci`:

```
λ> :i Test
data Test = Test    
instance [safe] Eq Test 
instance [safe] Show Test
```

But note that in the current GHC (7.10.2), the safe extension cannot be relied of the trust guarantee because of [this ghc bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9562).

Comment: Updated link to [Haskell Users Guide for Safe extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html)